# How to solve npm error with Heroku Deployment Forge RCDB?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I get the following error when I push to Heroku. - The page does not load so when I start heroku logs --tail ; I get the following code below. Now, the issue is I cannot make heads or tails if this is working or not at the moment. I've already done modifications to the existing extensions, but these work when testing locally, so the issue must be from something else.

```
2019-03-08T14:32:50.166539+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2019-03-08T14:33:59.394888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=forge-arc.herokuapp.com request_id=74fe5a1d-d2d5-442c-a3de-1c9ee014e975 fwd="194.196.127.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-08T14:38:48.490737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=forge-arc.herokuapp.com request_id=f1725df5-6dc8-4b1b-9d56-f454e5b208bf fwd="194.196.127.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-08T14:46:28.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user salazar.riva@protonmail.com
2019-03-08T14:47:53.061806+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user salazar.riva@protonmail.com
2019-03-08T14:47:53.061806+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7966b4d8 by user salazar.riva@protonmail.com
2019-03-08T14:47:54.423439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-08T14:47:58.756355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-08T14:48:01.251642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-08T14:48:01.233805+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-08T14:48:01.086307+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.086322+00:00 app[web.1]: > forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start /app
2019-03-08T14:48:01.086324+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/start.js
2019-03-08T14:48:01.086325+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167512+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167516+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167517+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167518+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167519+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './static'
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167521+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167522+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167524+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167525+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167527+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/start.js:15:3)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167528+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167529+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167530+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167532+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.167533+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
2019-03-08T14:48:01.172782+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.181772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1038-aws
2019-03-08T14:48:01.181932+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v11.11.0
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182200+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182333+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182443+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start: `node bin/start.js`
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182522+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182619+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182710+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start script 'node bin/start.js'.
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182891+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the forge-rcdb package,
2019-03-08T14:48:01.182981+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183077+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183162+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node bin/start.js
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183252+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183343+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs forge-rcdb
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183525+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls forge-rcdb
2019-03-08T14:48:01.183616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-08T14:48:01.187629+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.187773+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2019-03-08T14:48:01.187857+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2019-03-08T14:48:01.327292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-03-08T14:48:05.570034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-03-08T14:48:07.840573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-08T14:48:07.817098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-03-08T14:48:07.651138+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.651153+00:00 app[web.1]: > forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start /app
2019-03-08T14:48:07.651155+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/start.js
2019-03-08T14:48:07.651156+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724604+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:651
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724608+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724609+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724611+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724612+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './static'
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724614+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724615+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:575:25)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724617+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724618+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724619+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/start.js:15:3)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724621+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724622+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:810:10)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724623+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724625+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.724626+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3)
2019-03-08T14:48:07.729882+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.735943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1038-aws
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736108+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736247+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v11.11.0
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736365+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736491+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736595+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start: `node bin/start.js`
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736783+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736871+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the forge-rcdb@4.0.0 start script 'node bin/start.js'.
2019-03-08T14:48:07.736960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the forge-rcdb package,
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node bin/start.js
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737412+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737499+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs forge-rcdb
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737592+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737675+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls forge-rcdb
2019-03-08T14:48:07.737763+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-03-08T14:48:07.741834+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.742043+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2019-03-08T14:48:07.742155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2019-03-08T14:48:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-08T14:51:17.175542+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=forge-arc.herokuapp.com request_id=c3f21b41-7e75-417f-9419-107ceeeaaf92 fwd="194.196.127.82" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can you please give me a hand? I can see that the error is at node bin/start.js, but that makes no sense. That part is unchanged.

Comment: Are you developing a react app? Also, what cmd did you type out on the cmd line to throw this stack trace?

Comment: This is basically a build for forge RCDB. It does use react and they are mainly extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The original build command from the README was missing the bit to the build the server - can add the following to your build command to fix this:

```
npm run build-server && npm run build-prod && NODE_ENV=production npm start
```

Can refer to my PR [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/pull/62) for details.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but that did not really solve the whole issue. But I'm trying to narrow this one error at a time, so I changed in package.json at "start" into what you stated above. Here is the error I get now: https://pastebin.com/g4anKbpn